# Where do I get support when graph.microsoft.com suddenly starts returning errors for requests that were recently working?

Tags: json, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

This morning, multiple client accounts started returning this error when attempting to use their refresh_token to obtain a new access token:

`refreshAccessToken` error response:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_client",
    "error_description": "AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials. AADSTS50012: No client secret is provisioned in the store.",
    "error_codes": [70002, 50012],
    "timestamp": "2018-04-06 08:39:48Z",
    "trace_id": "40f2883e-68c2-4a15-87e9-8544c3430c00",
    "correlation_id": "a3536a53-b5ad-4494-ba43-a039c6bcfb45"
}
```

This smells like a system problem.  Where/how does one contact Microsoft or do they report system status errors somewhere?

Thanks!

Comment: Without seeing how you're obtaining your token it's a little hard to tell what is going on here. Can you provide a code sample?

Comment: Apparently, the entire system was down.  It has since resolved itself.

Answer (score 1):

There is a feedback forum for each Azure service area that you can use to report a bug. You can make a post here:

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the correct link:

> https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues

Its the Issue Tracker for the Graph Documentation, but there are multiple non Documentation related bugs submitted.

There seems no direct way to report a bug
 (got this link from the support site https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/support)